# Disable lazy loading when entity implements from JsonSerializabelInterface

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

My entity is like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\WordRepository")
     */
    class Word implements \JsonSerializable
    {
        const SOURCE_OXFORD = 'oxford';

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $word;



        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Definition", mappedBy="word")
         */
        private $definitions;


        /// other prorperties and setter/getters
        public function jsonSerialize()
        {
            return [
                'word' => $this->word,
                'definitions' => $this->definitions,
            ];
        }
    }
```

the `Definition` entity also has `reversedBy` relationship to `Word` and also it implemented from `JsonSerializable`.

Now when I find an specific word, I have to iterate over definitions to have access to all `Definition`s (because of lazy loading I think). like this

```
  foreach ($word->getDefinitions()  as $definition) {
      dump($definition->getDefinition());
  }
```

But I don't want to iterate over definitions. I want to access to all definitions when I `json_encode` the `$word`

Now my question is: How to disable lazy loading when an entity implemented from `JsonSerializabelInterface`?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing infrastructure related code with the domain and also trying to hack Doctrine itself? Remove the interface from the entity and use a [serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) to do the hard job for you.

Your domain will get free of such low level issues like serialization and you will become more flexible as entities can get serialized in many ways/formats, depending on the use case.

Comment: thanks mike. I used `serializer` but it has some performance issues when I have a relation between `Definition` and another entity that I didn't mention it in my question.

Comment: I solved my problem by using `JSM\Serializer`. thanks anyway ;)